# JMeter leaving protocol in HTTP request sampler empty

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter v3.2 and I put up a really simple test plan for testing something. I have a csv file where I save all URLs acquired by a crawler. The URLs are just normal (http://something.com).

After reading those in from the CSV Config and writing them into my HTTP request sampler I get the following issue. The problem comes with the default protocol of JMeter which turns my request URL into this:

GET `http://[http://something.com/]/.`

Is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: In your `CSV` have only the domain name, not the protocol. If you have different protocols, then you need to add that in a separate column e.g. `protocol,domain_name` Please post your HTTP request snapshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never put anything but ip address or hostname into `Server Name or IP` input of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

If you are getting the whole URL from CSV file - use `Path` input instead like:

[image: JMeter full URL in Path]

Demo (as per [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)

[image: JMeter View Results tree]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guide to learn more about parameterisation of your JMeter test with CSV files.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!